# Oracle SQL: how to distinct column values over row groups?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to do following data transformation using Oracle SQL:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it at presentation layer,  In `SQL` you can use `row_number()` :

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by colA order by colB) = 1 then colA end) as colA, colB
from table t
order by colA, colB;
```